# Does the DM Scranton office have more than one exit?

Tags: the-office, set-design

In U.S. adaptation of *The Office*, we typically see Dunder-Mifflin Scranton employees/guests walking in and out of the main front door across from the receptionist's desk to enter/exit the office. However, this got me to thinking: surely that building doesn't have only ONE way in and out of an office suite.

Are there any other entrances that are available for use? Especially for the employees in the annex? Granted, yes you wouldn't want guests coming in that way, but what if there was a (real, not Dwight-simulated) fire? How would annex employees get out?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Yes, there are several exits.

In S05E14 (Stress Relief, Part 1), Dwight stages a fire and everyone tries escaping. During this scene, once they notice the "fire" they attempt a total of **four exit doors**.

After they try those doors and have no luck, Michael freaks out and yells, "okay we're trapped, everyone for themselves!", implying that there're no more exits for them to try.

#### Confirmed exits:

- The main entrance
- Next to Meredith's desk
- Staircase (from either the main office area or the annex)
- Another door in the annex

[image]

Comment: Wait, the men's room has two entrances? And no stalls? And the women's room has a seating area (top-left corner)? Your map raises many new questions, lol.

Comment: @JJJ Yes, the women's bathroom has a seating area. The boys go in there when Michael takes the girls to the steamtown mall (S03E22 Women's Appreciation). And I'm assuming the door off the men's bathroom is a closet.

Comment: It doesn't seem to match with [this picture](https://i.imgur.com/OOAlvGC.jpg) though. Looks like the door on the right (in my picture) is a stall. Also weird, the door on the left opens to the toilet (based on the hinges), hitting someone who is standing their doing his business..

Comment: @JJJ Yes, it's just a stall then. And the door to the left in your picture probably originally opened to what is now Ryan's office, but then they closed it off and made a new opening from the kitchen. I'm guessing though.

Comment: Here's another floor plan image, with this one including both the bathroom stall *and* the door that leads to Ryan's office. But, if you look at images for Ryan's office there doesn't appear to be a door opening (so they must have closed it off once they repurposed the closet). https://images.app.goo.gl/oDV4iTYwf768MTgS6

Comment: I'm trying to find a full floor layout of the building (I'm sure since The Office production stopped, the studio re-modeled it long since). so how are the halls arranged outside of the DM office space? I get the doors now, but I'm still confused as to how the building is laid out. The main entrance leads to the elevator, that's made very clear, but the two back entrances and the Annex stairwell entrance are what baffles me.

Comment: @MissouriSpartan I believe that'd be a completely different question.

Comment: @Charles, unfortunately, it's not. I tried asking in the most logical, factual way, asking for factual information and got shut down as "trivial" and "off-topic" like clockwork.

Comment: @MissouriSpartan I just meant that it's not within the scope of this post. Honestly it takes a good amount of experience both in asking and fielding questions to get a good feel for what's on-topic when it comes to questions of this nature. Don't take it personal though :)

Comment: @Charles, I know. :) I'm just saying I tried, and got shut down right away, is all. I feel like the question was on-topic, personally. It was specifically asking about set design and what the building layout was supposed to be either in or out-of-universe. 3 other people decided it was off-topic and shut me down within 1 hour of posting, so I deleted the question. IMO, voting to close should not be allowed until at least 24 hours have passed and other viewers have had a chance to read and comment to be sure it isn't actually on-topic after all

Answer (score 4):

Yes I know for sure there is a backstair case. Here is a clip of Dwight dragging Stanley from the annex through a hallway in the back down a staircase that leads to the front door of the building downstairs.

.

Comment: Where in the planimetry (https://i.yapx.ru/5kBU.jpg) is the corridor (https://youtu.be/gK0omJb6sa8?t=103) that takes to the stairs?